# es6 Generator while(true)

Tags: javascript

start to learning generator, i am encounter the following script.

I am confused by first `next()`, why the console.log is not printed for the very first next().

```
function* callee() {
    console.log('callee: ' + (yield));
}
function* caller() {
    while (true) {
        yield* callee();
    }
}
```

---

```
> let callerObj = caller();

> callerObj.next() // start
{ value: undefined, done: false } 
// why console.log is not returning 'callee' ??

> callerObj.next('a')
callee: a
{ value: undefined, done: false }

> callerObj.next('b')
callee: b
{ value: undefined, done: false }
```

Comment: whoever leave that negative there, leave your reason! i am asking something which i am confused with.

Comment: This article helped me understand generators and some of their practical applications.  https://davidwalsh.name/es6-generators

Answer (score 5, accepted):

When you have a generator it *starts* in a suspended phase and the first `next` call runs the generator up to the *first* yield point.  When you "yield from" a sub-generator, each time.  If you add logging to the entry points of both your functions you will see this:

```
function* callee() {
  console.log('Callee is running up to the first yield point');
  console.log('callee: ' + (yield));
}
function* caller() {
  console.log('Caller is running up to the first yield point');
  while (true) {
    yield* callee();
  }
}
```

When you run this implementation using your test code you will see:

```
> let t = caller()
> t.next()
Caller is running up to the first yield point
Callee is running up to the first yield point
Object {value: undefined, done: false}
```

Comment: i guess the first pause is yield* callee(); or console.log('callee: ' + (yield)); ?

Comment: The latter, `console.log('callee: ' + (yield))`

Answer (score 3):

When starting the generator (`callerObj.next()`), it always goes up to the first `yield`.
Since you are delegating (`yield *`) to another generator, that yield would be the one in `callee`:

```
function* callee() {
    console.log('callee: ' + (yield));
                // this yield ^^^^^
}
```

Here the generator stops *before* executing `console.log`. If you were to `yield` a value back, this would be the return `value` of your first `callerObj.next()` call:

```
function* callee() {
    console.log('callee: ' + (yield 'value'));
}
```

The next `callerObj.next('a')` call will then replace the value at `yield` with `'a'` and call `console.log`. In pseudo-code:

```
console.log('callee: ' + 'a');
// `yield` is replaced with 'a' for this invocation
```

It will then run until it encounters the same `yield` again (since you are in an infinite loop).

Comment: `yield` is basically = to "pause" in terms of code execution where `generatorObj.next( ... )` = "play".  That's at least how I conceptualize it.

Comment: i guess the first pause is yield* callee(); or console.log('callee: ' + (yield)); ?

Comment: The first pause happens at the `yield` in `console.log('callee: ' + (yield));`.